# Изменение input [type=range] колесиком мышки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как изменять значение input [type=range] колесиком мышки при hover-e над его родительским div.
При hover-e над родительском div нужно чтобы переставал работать скорлл страницы.

```js
const snipsnapp_volume_control_slider = document.querySelector('.snipsnapp_volume_control_slider');
const snipsnapp_volume_control_progress = document.querySelector('.snipsnapp_volume_control_progress');
snipsnapp_volume_control_slider.oninput = function(){
  snipsnapp_volume_control_progress.style.width = `${this.value}%`;
};
```

```css
.snipsnapp_volume_control_wrapper{
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.snipsnapp_volume_control_slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(2.5em - 2px);
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: inherit;
    z-index: 5;
}

.snipsnapp_volume_control_slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    opacity: 0;
    appearance: none;
    width: 0;
}
.snipsnapp_volume_control_progress{
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #dc3545;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.snipsnapp_volume_control_slider:before {
    content: attr(value);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    color: #ffc107;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="snipsnapp_volume_control_wrapper btn btn-lg border border-danger p-0 me-4" title="Volume">
    <input type="range" value="50" min="0.01" max="100" step="0.01" class="snipsnapp_volume_control_slider">
    <div class="snipsnapp_volume_control_progress"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно это сделать с помощью события [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event):

```js
const snipsnapp_volume_control_slider = document.querySelector('.snipsnapp_volume_control_slider');
const snipsnapp_volume_control_progress = document.querySelector('.snipsnapp_volume_control_progress');

const updateSliderValue = (value) => snipsnapp_volume_control_progress.style.width = `${value}%`;

snipsnapp_volume_control_slider.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // Убираем скроллинг
  
  const change = e.deltaY > 0 ? -1 : 1;
  const currentValue = +snipsnapp_volume_control_slider.value;
  const step = 1; //+snipsnapp_volume_control_slider.step;
  
  snipsnapp_volume_control_slider.value = change * step + currentValue;
  
  updateSliderValue(snipsnapp_volume_control_slider.value);
});

snipsnapp_volume_control_slider.oninput = function() {
  updateSliderValue(this.value);
};
```

```css
.snipsnapp_volume_control_wrapper{
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.snipsnapp_volume_control_slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(2.5em - 2px);
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: inherit;
    z-index: 5;
}

.snipsnapp_volume_control_slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    opacity: 0;
    appearance: none;
    width: 0;
}
.snipsnapp_volume_control_progress{
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #dc3545;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.snipsnapp_volume_control_slider:before {
    content: attr(value);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    color: #ffc107;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="snipsnapp_volume_control_wrapper btn btn-lg border border-danger p-0 me-4" title="Volume">
    <input type="range" value="50" min="0.01" max="100" step="0.01" class="snipsnapp_volume_control_slider">
    <div class="snipsnapp_volume_control_progress"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, пока у меня не работает в проекте, только в песочнице, но думаю что разберусь что к чему. Еще нюанс есть, при скролле инпута также происходит общий скролл страницы и получается что инпут убегает от курсора. Можно как нибудь отключать общий скролл пока курсор находится над snipsnapp_volume_control_wrapper?

Comment: @Юра Да, конечно, можно. Добавил в код, можете проверить. Всё что нужно сделать - это добавить `e.preventDefault()`, чтобы отменить его стандартное поведение и делать только то что нам надо

Answer (score 0):

Вот ссылка на доку по событиям мыши jQuery ([ссылка](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/))

Вот пример использования ([ссылка](https://anton.shevchuk.name/wp-demo/jquery-tutorials-6/mouse.html))

Вот ссылка на плагин по работе с КОЛЁСИКОМ мышки ([ссылка](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel))